# Mongoose how to use .add to reuse schema with virtual

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a use-case where I want to define a schema with a virtual and then use that schema in multiple places. To do so I found the .add property in the mongoose docs as seen [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add).

The behavior of this is not what I expect though and by default the virtual does not populate. I looked at the specific schema generated and found that after creating it by using ".add" it does not retain all of the fields of the original schema. Specifically within the "virtuals" object the "path" property becomes an empty object instead of a string and in the "tree" object the virtual is missing altogether.

I looked through the actual dependency and found that this is a result of how ".add" works internally namely it calls a function called "merge" which copies many of the properties onto the new schema. Notably the merge function does nothing with the "tree" object on the schema though and in the case of the virtuals it copies the name/options/getters/setters, but does nothing for the "path". I manually added the missing parts to the merge function and it fixed my issue, but I'd like to know if I'm just using this incorrectly or if this is a bug in the mongoose library as updating the dependency directly isn't a valid solution for me.

Here's an example of how I'm instantiating the schemas

```
const testBase= data.db.Schema({
    test: {type: String, required: true}
});
testBase.virtual('testVirtual')
.get(function () {
    return "test";
});
testBase.set('toObject', {virtuals: true});
testBase.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true});

const testParent = data.db.Schema();
testParent.add(testBase);
testParent.set('toObject', {virtuals: true});
testParent.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true});
```

In this example if I use "testBase" as my schema in a model it will correctly use the virtual, while if I use "testParent" it will not. When my expectation is that they should behave identically.

Getting the JSON of the two schemas shows this for testBase

```
{
"$id": 24,
"_indexes": [],
"_userProvidedOptions": {
    "toJSON": {
        "virtuals": true
    },
    "toObject": {
        "virtuals": true
    }
},
"aliases": {},
"callQueue": [],
"childSchemas": [],
"inherits": {},
"methodOptions": {},
"methods": {},
"nested": {},
"obj": {
    "test": {
        "required": true
    }
},
"options": {
    "_id": true,
    "autoIndex": null,
    "bufferCommands": true,
    "capped": false,
    "discriminatorKey": "__t",
    "id": true,
    "minimize": true,
    "noId": false,
    "noVirtualId": false,
    "read": null,
    "shardKey": null,
    "strict": true,
    "toJSON": {
        "virtuals": true
    },
    "toObject": {
        "virtuals": true
    },
    "typeKey": "type",
    "validateBeforeSave": true,
    "versionKey": "__v"
},
"paths": {
    "_id": {
        "$immutable": null,
        "_index": null,
        "getters": [],
        "instance": "ObjectID",
        "options": {
            "auto": true
        },
        "path": "_id",
        "setters": [
            null
        ],
        "validators": []
    },
    "test": {
        "$immutable": null,
        "_index": null,
        "enumValues": [],
        "getters": [],
        "instance": "String",
        "isRequired": true,
        "options": {
            "required": true
        },
        "originalRequiredValue": true,
        "path": "test",
        "regExp": null,
        "setters": [],
        "validators": [
            {
                "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                "type": "required"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"plugins": [],
"query": {},
"s": {
    "hooks": {
        "_posts": {},
        "_pres": {}
    }
},
"singleNestedPaths": {},
"statics": {},
"subpaths": {},
"tree": {
    "_id": {
        "auto": true
    },
    "test": {
        "required": true
    },
    "testVirtual": {
        "getters": [
            null
        ],
        "options": {},
        "path": "testVirtual",
        "setters": []
    }
},
"virtuals": {
    "testVirtual": {
        "getters": [
            null
        ],
        "options": {},
        "path": "testVirtual",
        "setters": []
    }
}
```

}

And this for testParent

```
{
"$id": 25,
"_indexes": [],
"_userProvidedOptions": {
    "toJSON": {
        "virtuals": true
    },
    "toObject": {
        "virtuals": true
    }
},
"aliases": {},
"callQueue": [],
"childSchemas": [],
"inherits": {},
"methodOptions": {},
"methods": {},
"nested": {},
"options": {
    "_id": true,
    "autoIndex": null,
    "bufferCommands": true,
    "capped": false,
    "discriminatorKey": "__t",
    "id": true,
    "minimize": true,
    "noId": false,
    "noVirtualId": false,
    "read": null,
    "shardKey": null,
    "strict": true,
    "toJSON": {
        "virtuals": true
    },
    "toObject": {
        "virtuals": true
    },
    "typeKey": "type",
    "validateBeforeSave": true,
    "versionKey": "__v"
},
"paths": {
    "_id": {
        "$immutable": null,
        "_index": null,
        "getters": [],
        "instance": "ObjectID",
        "options": {
            "auto": true
        },
        "path": "_id",
        "setters": [
            null
        ],
        "validators": []
    },
    "test": {
        "$immutable": null,
        "_index": null,
        "enumValues": [],
        "getters": [],
        "instance": "String",
        "isRequired": true,
        "options": {
            "required": true
        },
        "originalRequiredValue": true,
        "path": "test",
        "regExp": null,
        "setters": [],
        "validators": [
            {
                "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                "type": "required"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"plugins": [],
"query": {},
"s": {
    "hooks": {
        "_posts": {},
        "_pres": {}
    }
},
"singleNestedPaths": {},
"statics": {},
"subpaths": {},
"tree": {
    "_id": {
        "auto": true
    },
    "test": {
        "required": true
    }
},
"virtuals": {
    "testVirtual": {
        "getters": [
            null
        ],
        "options": {},
        "path": {},
        "setters": []
    }
}
```

}

If you compare the missing schemas you can see which fields are missing. If anyone knows the correct way to use this functionality or examples along these lines I would appreciate it. (My testing was done with mongoose version 5.7.8)